# Message: Call to private method Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile() from context 'Firebase'

Tags: php, firebase

Does this error have anything to do with the Firebase version? If not, how do I solve this issue?

```
private static function fromJsonFile(string $filePath): self
{
    try {
        $file = new \SplFileObject($filePath);
        $json = (string) $file->fread($file->getSize());
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("{$filePath} can not be read: {$e->getMessage()}");
    }

    try {
        $serviceAccount = self::fromJson($json);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(\sprintf('%s could not be parsed to a Service Account: %s', $filePath, $e->getMessage()));
    }

    return $serviceAccount;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Kreait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397030/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-method-kreait)

Comment: Not exactly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could you please put the error message in the question body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is from [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) and shows a private method from the `ServiceAccount` class that can not be called directly since release 5.0 of the SDK.

Straight from the [troubleshooting section in the documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.11.0/troubleshooting.html#call-to-private-undefined-method):

You probably followed a tutorial article or video targeted at a 4.x version, and your code looks like this:

```php
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');
$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();
```

Change it to the following:

```php
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');

$database = $factory->createDatabase();
```

Comment: Yes,the error had something to do with the version. Unfortunately,changing code came with some complications.

Comment: I was able to fix them by lowering the firebase version to 4.18. 5.0 made everything hard.By following this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136746/firebase-connection-with-codeigniter-in-php it was almost effortless! Thanks for your help!